# Date Datatype working other datatype not working Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

When I select using `date` format it is working e.g:

```
select * 
from driverdetails 
where licenserenewaldate between '2015-01-27' and '2015-02-27'
```

When I'm using `varchar` or `text` `(27-01-2015)`, it is not retrieving.

```
select * 
from driverdetails 
where licenserenewaldate between '27-01-2015' and '27-02-2015'
```

It is not working. It's showing empty value.

Comment: The date format is by default `yyyy-mm-dd`. Check for the formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a POST or GET request for submitting the data to be filtered, you can use `strtotime()` function first before including it in your query.

Check out this [strtotime manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Format the data in `yyyy-mm-dd` by doing:

```
$yourDateData=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($yourDateData));
```

You can refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more date format.

Comment: Yeah,Thanks it is working,Is there any possible to get from different data types....

Comment: @selva - What different data types? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below and I hope you will get the results you want

```
select * 
from driverdetails 
where licenserenewaldate between str_to_date('27-01-2015','%d-%m-%Y') AND 
str_to_date('27-02-2015','%d-%m-%Y')
```